# How pylint does not raise no-member message in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse, pylint

I wrote code like this.

```
from argparse import Namespace

class Config(Namespace): 
    def __init__(self, filename):
        config = yaml.load(open(filename, 'r'))

        super(Config, self).__init__(**config)

config = Config('some/path/where/yaml/file/exist')

print(config.some_attr)
```

then pyline raise no-member warning like this.

`Instance of 'Config' has no 'some_attr' member pylint(no-member)`

But some of argparse method does not raise no-member warning.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("test")
parser.add_argument('--config', type=str, default='config')
args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

args.test # no warning
args.config # no warning
```

This code does not raise any warning in pylint.

I was curious, so I looked at the corresponding code in github. But ArgumentParser.parse_knwon_args's first return value is Namespace object too.

How can I fix my custom Config class does not raise warning message? I don't want insert '# pylint: disable=no-member' in my code block. Is there a solution in the module(class)?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `__getattribute__` function which will 'safely' grab attributes from the class and pylint will no longer complain.

```py
class MyAttributeClass:
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Be warned that this means pylint will not detect references to members that won't ever exist, so bugs can creep into your code this way. Only use this for classes that are expected to have dynamic attributes.